# Can I add some css for every file in postcss with webpack

Tags: webpack, postcss

Currently I am working on a project where we are migrating a website by rewriting components one-by-one to a new solution. Theres is a lot of existing SASS styling, including variables and mixins.

sass-loader didn't play nice in our css modules setup, so we're now trying to use a PostCSS setup with, amongst others, an import plugin, variables support, etc.
I want to make the existing variables, of the old website, available in all new files.

Before when we used the sass-loader, I could pass a `data` option that contained a bunch of `@imports` pointing to the variable files.

I wasn't able to find something alike in PostCSS or an include plugin.

Maybe I didn't look right, ideas anyone?

Comment: I guess what you need is postcss-partial-import ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-partial-import

Comment: I've been looking into that, but it would require me to do an `@import '../../variables.sass'` in every css module file. I want it to be part of the configuration, so I don't have to think about it.

Meanwhile we've resolved to copying the variables over as-we-need-them into a new file. Over time this will also clean up some old unused stuff.

Still, it would be nice to find an answer!

Comment: Well I use to have a main.css which includes my variables at the very top of the document, after that a import all my components which also make use of the variables that are stored in my variables.scss and it works like a charm. I don't have to repetitivley include the variables in every single components sheet.